# Skipping keyword execution in Robot Framework

Tags: automation, robotframework

We are using robot Framework for automation. We have a scenario where we want to skip execution of some keywords based on an argument provided or a tag. These keywords are part of suite setup of test cases and in some scenarios, like for development environment, we want to skip execution of just these keyword.

Currently we pass in a global variable and use the RETURN FROM KEYWORD IF logic.
Could this be done with tags or is there any other better approach?

Comment: How about `Run Keyword If    '${ENVIRONMENT}' != 'prod'    keyword with logic which is suppose to execute on non prod environment`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can Robot Framework test suites be called with command-line parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66889745/can-robot-framework-test-suites-be-called-with-command-line-parameters)

Comment: Thanks for the links. Guides me to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Run keyword if](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20If) to conditionally run your keyword

```
Run keyword if  $environment=="dev"  the keyword
```

You can then [set the variable on the command](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#setting-variables-in-command-line). For example:

```
robot --variable environment:dev tests
```